# Generate a list from 'A',...'Z','AA',...'AZ' in Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Thanks for viewing my question. I am using the `openpyxl` to fetch data from a database to make a **xlsx file** for it. And I will use those data to do some calculation and show those results in the same row. So with the excel, I think I will use from the **column['A'] to ['AT']** at this time, and I might extend the length of the row in the future, I would like to know whether these is a way to **generate a list like['A','B','C'....'AZ'..] with a number for example, 1 will give ['A'] and 2 will give ['B'] ** so I can use the list with A index** instead of manual creating those cells.

My code will be like:

```
for k in hourly_result:  # Hour_result is data fetched from database

    approved_filler_counter_helper(k, container)  # A calculation function

    # Fill the data into xlsx
    wb1['A{}'.format(i + 2)] = container.result_1
    wb1['B{}'.format(i + 3)] = container.result_2
    ...............
```

Comment: So maybe like `get_letter(10)` would get `J` but `get_letter(28)` would get `AB`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner:

```
>>> import string
>>> [f"{i}{j}" for i in ["", "A"] for j in string.ascii_uppercase]

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ']
```